# Jailbreak iPad 3 ("the new iPad") iOS 9.1

Tags: ios, ipad, jailbreak

Is it possible to jailbreak iOS 9.1 on an iPad 3, WiFi model? If not, I also have the possibility to update to iOS 9.3.5.

Answer (score 2):

A beta of the [Home Depot iOS 9.1-9.3.4 32-bit Mixtape Player](http://wall.supplies) supports your device on iOS 9.1.

There is no jailbreak for iOS 9.3.5, so take precautions with your jailbreak, especially since Prometheus does not support 32-bit devices.